# Interop from clojure a with non-standard iterative java API

Tags: clojure, iteration, seq, clojure-java-interop

I am working in clojure with a java class which provides a retrieval API for a domain specific binary file holding a series of records.

The java class is initialized with a file and then provides a `.query` method which returns an instance of an inner class which has only one method `.next`, thus not playing nicely with the usual java collections API. Neither the outer nor inner class implements any interface.

The `.query` method may return null instead of the inner class. The `.next` method returns a record string or null if no further records are found, it may return null immediately upon the first call.

How do I make this java API work well from within clojure without writing further java classes?

The best I could come up with is:

```
(defn get-records
  [file query-params]
  (let [tr (JavaCustomFileReader. file)]
    (if-let [inner-iter (.query tr query-params)] ; .query may return null                                                               
      (loop [it inner-iter
             results []]
       (if-let [record (.next it)]
         (recur it (conj results record))
         results))
      [])))
```

This gives me a vector of results to work with the clojure seq abstractions. Are there other ways to expose a seq from the java API, either with lazy-seq or using protocols?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but what do you mean by a non-standard Java API?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus specifically I mean the Java code doesn't provide a java.util.Iterator nor implement java.lang.Iterable . Logically the java code is providing iteration but without a connection to the standard API for doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without dropping to `lazy-seq`:

```
(defn record-seq
  [q]
  (take-while (complement nil?) (repeatedly #(.next q))))
```

Instead of `(complement nil?)` you could also just use `identity` if `.next` does not return boolean `false`.

```
(defn record-seq
  [q]
  (take-while identity (repeatedly #(.next q))))
```

I would also restructure a little bit the entry points.

```
(defn query
  [rdr params]
  (when-let [q (.query rdr params)]
    (record-seq q)))

(defn query-file
  [file params]
  (with-open [rdr (JavaCustomFileReader. file)]
    (doall (query rdr params))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not lazy as it would be if you were using Iterable but you can fill the gap with lazy-seq as follows.

```
(defn query-seq [q]
  (lazy-seq
    (when-let [val (.next q)]
      (cons val (query-seq q)))))
```

Maybe you shoul wrap the query method to protect yourself from the first null value as well.

Comment: Move the `lazy-seq` up around the `when-let`.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like a good fit for [`lazy-seq`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/lazy-seq):

```
(defn query [file query]
  (.query (JavaCustomFileReader. file) query))

(defn record-seq [query]
  (when query
    (when-let [v (.next query)]
      (cons v (lazy-seq (record-seq query))))))

;; usage:
(record-seq (query "filename" "query params"))
```